# fpdf library not workin on WAMP server

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I try to generate a PDF report using `fpdf` Library. First of all I tried pimple test example on `fpdf` but it gives me two errors.

> No such file or directory
>   and 
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'fpdf/fpdf.php'

But there is a folder that I created named `fpdf` and my test `pdf` is inside that folder.

I am using `PHP 7.3.5` in `WAMP server`

```php
 <?php

     require('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 

     $pdf = new FPDF();
     $pdf->AddPage();

     $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
     $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

     $pdf->Output("testsuccess.pdf",'F');
 ?>
```

Comment: where is this page (that you have above code) located?

Comment: I created folder named fpdf and the above fpdf.php file and its css files are inside that fpdf folder.

Comment: Change your require to simply `require('fpdf.php');` if you put the code above into the SAME folder as `fpdf.php`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why one might run into this error and thus a good checklist of what to check first helps considerably.

Let's consider that we are troubleshooting the following line:
**Manually  check your path**

```
$path = "/path/to/file";

echo "Path : $path";

require "$path";
```

Then in terminal

```
cat <file path pasted>
```